# Additional content in the generated executable file when debug option is enabled during compilation

Tags: debugging, compilation, executable

I have small source code which I tried compiling in 2 different ways : 
1.With No Debug option
2.With Debug option enabled

I noticed that when I add the debug enable compiler option during compilation the generated executable file is bigger than the executable file generated when the debug enable option is not added.
What is the additional content that is being added to the original executable content due to debug enable.?

Comment: How is that related to the two different languages C and C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you compile an executable with the debug option, it adds *debug information* to the executable. This information is used by debuggers to show things like variable names, function names and line numbers, when debugging your program. This makes things far easier to track compared to debugging your application and having to look at assembly code.

The compiler disables optimising the code (except for the simplest optimisations) in debug mode to facilitate the mapping of the source code to the machine code. This also means that any unused code will be seen during debugging, and if it's actually is meant to be used, then you can investigate why it isn't being called.

Another thing the debug option can do is add many checks to make sure your program is functioning properly. Things like:

- null pointer checks
- divide by zero checks
- array access checks
- memory access checks
- integer overflow checks
- checking for proper use of the standard library functions
- zeroing every uninitialised variable

If you fail a check, then the program either alerts you via a message box or another output method, or fails in a predictable way.

Comment: Great. That helps. But I get another question on reading your line, _The compiler disables optimising the code (except for the simplest optimisations) in debug mode_ Does that mean, i will not be able to debug with the actual optimization I need.? For example, I perfrom opimization for size. But due to debug option being enabled, compiler disables the optimization. So I will not be debugging an expected output executable. Is it correct.?

Comment: @M.Ravi When debugging, optimisations should not be priority; debugging should be.

Comment: Understood. Thanks again.